# Check if a device is in use [UWP]

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, winrt-async

I'm using UWP API from C++ via WinRT and want to check if a camera is in use (before trying to access or open it):

```
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;

auto cameras = DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(DeviceClass::VideoCapture);
// choose camera...
for (const auto camera_info : camera_results)
{
    // camera_info.IsEnabled() returns 1, I guess it's not about in use or not
}
```

Is there a way to get device (camera in this case) state, if it's in use or not?

Even using WinAPI not WinRT

Comment: [Your proposed design has a TOCTOU error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)

Comment: @BenVoigt yes but that's point here

Comment: What's wrong with trying to open it and deal with the error code if you can't?

Comment: IsEnabled() indicates whether this device is enabled. According to its meaning, it seems can check if a device is in use.